# what is the proper physical build of a fantasy adveturer?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

I am trying to make a game and I want the characters to look somewhat like they could actually be someone who goes around slaying monsters, fighting evil over lords and their henchmen, all while still being able to hike several miles back to the nearest village. I also don't want to over sexualize the characters for sake of realism. So the only things I am looking for are weight and muscle mass. I also want them to look like fighting monsters is something they do all the time, in other words a part of there every day life.

Comment: Outside of the assertion that he or she should be physically fit, this is going to be opinion-based.

Comment: @Alexander even physically fit is subjective.  This question is entirely opinion based.  I don't see a way to salvage it.

Comment: You over sexualize your characters to sell copies of your game not for realism. People buy it and hopefully stay because you have solid content and stories in it to keep them engaged.

Comment: Sorry but this has been closed for being primarily opinion based.  It's a good question, but it can't be answered in the format that the stack exchange network requires.

Comment: He in short. He is tall. He is thin. He is chubby. He has big, strong, calloused hands. He has small, delicate, smooth hands. He has a stubby nose. He has a long nose. He has a hooked nose. His eyes are steely blue. His eyes are pure black. His eyes are emerald green. His skin is milk white. His skin is olive brown. His skin is ruddy broze. His skin is blueish black. His hair is lustrous black. His hair is golden blond. His hair is fire red. He has bulging muscles. He is wiry. He has long legs. He has short legs. He is rakishly attractive. He has a forgettable face. He is handsome. He is ugly.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one.

Beyond the fact that they would be in reasonably physical shape different people will have different forms and appearances based on the sorts of training they have done.

For example some people will favour agility and speed.

Others brute strength.

Wizards probably don't spend much time lifting weights.

People (particularly in a standard fantasy environment) are unlikely to be heavily overweight but other than that pretty much anything goes.

Answer (score 2):

**Lean but strong**

Realistically these characters would be like hunter / rangers

[image]

Monsters are naturally stronger than humans so they'd kill them using arrows and/or traps. Evil overlords have more men and are better armed and armoured so again it would be ambushes, traps and arrows from afar.

You don't want bulky muscles because it's extra weight hiking back and extra calories to keep up the strength. Since you're using arrows against a stronger opponent, you don't want swords nor carry the weight of a sword while retreating back to cover. Equipment would likely serve dual purpose and a legitimate use to explain to passing patrols. Hunters and woodmen need bows, daggers and axes but a sword is hard to explain.

Comment: Although to most likely people roaming about that may get caught up in an adventure would be a woodsmen, but you may have the random other dude get flung into action, such as a farm hand, who may be a corn fed brute, or a soldier, that if conscripted could be any poor sap. However I have always hated the idea of the goliath warrior. Just too many calories to consume when in the wilderness.

Comment: Swords have good reach, and polearms even more so! Additionally, upper-body strength is very important in archery. It takes a lot to draw a bowstring! You're correct though in the basic premise that the strongest human is still never going to be a match for a monster. Humans are much better off focusing on our intrinsic superiorities. Endurance, and intelligence.

Comment: Swords and polearms are good for armed forces but useless for under manned rebel forces. You can't go toe to toe with a well equipped army.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter.  Your only listed requirement is cardio (long hikes).  You can have a strong heart and be any size and shape.  300 lbs people run marathons. 70 lbs people can't do a single push up or walk more than 5000 steps without becoming exhausted.  So it really doesn't matter what someone looks like, it is what is inside that counts.